# Google Maps incorrect GeoJSON rendering

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, geojson

I am trying to plot a GeoJSON LineString on Google Maps using Google Maps API.

I am getting the GeoJSON object as an AJAX response and am using "map.data.addGeoJson(data)" function to load the GeoJSON response on the map.

The GPS latitude and long points have all been ripped from .gpx files from Open Street Maps website and then put in the database. They are then compiled into GeoJSON format and then sent to the website.

The individual points are all in Germany, but the trajectory is rendered near Somalia.

Can anyone help me please?

The initMap function containing the AJAX request is as follows:

```
       function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {lat: 53.44620230866472, lng: 9.666813185187198},
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    });


    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ADDRESS TO SERVER/api/geodata/getLineString',
    data: {"usrid":3,"startd":"2016-04-17","endd":"2016-04-18"},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
    map.data.addGeoJson(response);
        },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    },
});
  }
```

The entire GeoJSON response is as below:

```
      {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        51.731921404763426,
        14.342405595236764
      ],
      [
        51.731914999999994,
        14.342412
      ],
      [
        51.73192399392278,
        14.342408729482642
      ],
      [
        51.73193,
        14.342416000000004
      ],
      [
        51.731934,
        14.342417000000001
      ],
      [
        51.73193,
        14.342411999999998
      ],
      [
        51.731926,
        14.342408
      ],
      [
        51.73192399392278,
        14.342408729482642
      ],
      [
        51.731921404763426,
        14.342405595236764
      ],
      [
        51.73199100000001,
        14.34214
      ],
      [
        51.73198299999999,
        14.342144
      ],
      [
        51.731987,
        14.342298000000001
      ],
      [
        51.731983,
        14.342302000000002
      ],
      [
        51.731983,
        14.342303999999999
      ],
      [
        51.73199100000001,
        14.342310000000001
      ],
      [
        51.731995000000005,
        14.342308
      ],
      [
        51.731998,
        14.342317
      ],
      [
        51.731999943503226,
        14.34232428813586
      ],
      [
        51.732002,
        14.342319000000002
      ],
      [
        51.732006000000005,
        14.342308000000003
      ],
      [
        51.732009999999995,
        14.342290999999996
      ],
      [
        51.73201799999999,
        14.342276
      ],
      [
        51.732025,
        14.342262999999999
      ],
      [
        51.732025,
        14.342252999999998
      ],
      [
        51.732032999999994,
        14.342243
      ],
      [
        51.732032999999994,
        14.342237000000003
      ],
      [
        51.73202500000001,
        14.342224000000002
      ],
      [
        51.73201799999999,
        14.342204999999996
      ],
      [
        51.73201,
        14.342184999999999
      ],
      [
        51.732002,
        14.342166
      ],
      [
        51.731995000000005,
        14.342153
      ],
      [
        51.731995000000005,
        14.342149000000001
      ],
      [
        51.73199100000001,
        14.34214
      ],
      [
        51.731976333334124,
        14.340528000002589
      ],
      [
        51.73196,
        14.340535
      ],
      [
        51.731934,
        14.340549
      ],
      [
        51.73190300000001,
        14.340559
      ],
      [
        51.731873,
        14.340569
      ],
      [
        51.731846000000004,
        14.340582
      ],
      [
        51.731815,
        14.340595
      ],
      [
        51.731789,
        14.340612000000002
      ],
      [
        51.731762,
        14.340625999999999
      ],
      [
        51.73173100000001,
        14.340643
      ],
      [
        51.731705,
        14.340658
      ],
      [
        51.731674,
        14.340673
      ],
      [
        51.731651,
        14.340681999999997
      ],
      [
        51.731621,
        14.340693
      ],
      [
        51.73160200000001,
        14.340705999999997
      ],
      [
        51.731586,
        14.340723
      ],
      [
        51.731567,
        14.340734000000003
      ],
      [
        51.731548,
        14.340740000000002
      ],
      [
        51.73153299999999,
        14.340748999999999
      ],
      [
        51.731514,
        14.340759
      ],
      [
        51.731495,
        14.340764000000002
      ],
      [
        51.731476,
        14.340768
      ],
      [
        51.731472,
        14.340768
      ],
      [
        51.731472,
        14.340765999999997
      ],
      [
        51.731468,
        14.340762
      ],
      [
        51.73146799999999,
        14.340772999999999
      ],
      [
        51.731468,
        14.340788
      ],
      [
        51.731472,
        14.340809
      ]
      ]
      },
  "properties": {
    "trajectoryid": "05BC2B9E-7350-4D55-B4BB-026EC0B2E65B",
    "color": "blue"
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the coordinates backwards. GeoJSON is `[longitude, latitude]`, not `[latitude, longitude]`.

See [positions](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions) in the documentation:

> "A position is represented by an array of numbers. There must be at least two elements, and may be more. The order of elements must follow x, y, z order (easting, northing, altitude for coordinates in a projected coordinate reference system, or **longitude, latitude, altitude for coordinates in a geographic coordinate reference system**)."

If I reverse the coordinates, the polyline appears in Germany.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 53.44620230866472,
      lng: 9.666813185187198
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  });
  // map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  map.data.addGeoJson(reverseData(geoJson));
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function reverseData(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.geometry.coordinates.length; i++) {
    data.geometry.coordinates[i] = [data.geometry.coordinates[i][1], data.geometry.coordinates[i][0]];
    var mrk = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: data.geometry.coordinates[i][1],
        lng: data.geometry.coordinates[i][0]
      },
      // map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(mrk.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  return data;
}
var geoJson = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        51.731921404763426,
        14.342405595236764
      ],
      [
        51.731914999999994,
        14.342412
      ],
      [
        51.73192399392278,
        14.342408729482642
      ],
      [
        51.73193,
        14.342416000000004
      ],
      [
        51.731934,
        14.342417000000001
      ],
      [
        51.73193,
        14.342411999999998
      ],
      [
        51.731926,
        14.342408
      ],
      [
        51.73192399392278,
        14.342408729482642
      ],
      [
        51.731921404763426,
        14.342405595236764
      ],
      [
        51.73199100000001,
        14.34214
      ],
      [
        51.73198299999999,
        14.342144
      ],
      [
        51.731987,
        14.342298000000001
      ],
      [
        51.731983,
        14.342302000000002
      ],
      [
        51.731983,
        14.342303999999999
      ],
      [
        51.73199100000001,
        14.342310000000001
      ],
      [
        51.731995000000005,
        14.342308
      ],
      [
        51.731998,
        14.342317
      ],
      [
        51.731999943503226,
        14.34232428813586
      ],
      [
        51.732002,
        14.342319000000002
      ],
      [
        51.732006000000005,
        14.342308000000003
      ],
      [
        51.732009999999995,
        14.342290999999996
      ],
      [
        51.73201799999999,
        14.342276
      ],
      [
        51.732025,
        14.342262999999999
      ],
      [
        51.732025,
        14.342252999999998
      ],
      [
        51.732032999999994,
        14.342243
      ],
      [
        51.732032999999994,
        14.342237000000003
      ],
      [
        51.73202500000001,
        14.342224000000002
      ],
      [
        51.73201799999999,
        14.342204999999996
      ],
      [
        51.73201,
        14.342184999999999
      ],
      [
        51.732002,
        14.342166
      ],
      [
        51.731995000000005,
        14.342153
      ],
      [
        51.731995000000005,
        14.342149000000001
      ],
      [
        51.73199100000001,
        14.34214
      ],
      [
        51.731976333334124,
        14.340528000002589
      ],
      [
        51.73196,
        14.340535
      ],
      [
        51.731934,
        14.340549
      ],
      [
        51.73190300000001,
        14.340559
      ],
      [
        51.731873,
        14.340569
      ],
      [
        51.731846000000004,
        14.340582
      ],
      [
        51.731815,
        14.340595
      ],
      [
        51.731789,
        14.340612000000002
      ],
      [
        51.731762,
        14.340625999999999
      ],
      [
        51.73173100000001,
        14.340643
      ],
      [
        51.731705,
        14.340658
      ],
      [
        51.731674,
        14.340673
      ],
      [
        51.731651,
        14.340681999999997
      ],
      [
        51.731621,
        14.340693
      ],
      [
        51.73160200000001,
        14.340705999999997
      ],
      [
        51.731586,
        14.340723
      ],
      [
        51.731567,
        14.340734000000003
      ],
      [
        51.731548,
        14.340740000000002
      ],
      [
        51.73153299999999,
        14.340748999999999
      ],
      [
        51.731514,
        14.340759
      ],
      [
        51.731495,
        14.340764000000002
      ],
      [
        51.731476,
        14.340768
      ],
      [
        51.731472,
        14.340768
      ],
      [
        51.731472,
        14.340765999999997
      ],
      [
        51.731468,
        14.340762
      ],
      [
        51.73146799999999,
        14.340772999999999
      ],
      [
        51.731468,
        14.340788
      ],
      [
        51.731472,
        14.340809
      ]
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "trajectoryid": "05BC2B9E-7350-4D55-B4BB-026EC0B2E65B",
    "color": "blue"
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```